# Error while parsing with ANTLR is thrown silently (possibly due to multithreading) - C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, antlr4

I am using ANTLR to parse some files. Each file defines a list of dependencies. As this may require a lot of large files to be loaded, I am trying to multithread this.

*When running on one thread:*
An error is being thrown on the indicated line of VisitScope. I know this because it was failing here before I implemented multithreading.

*When running on multiple threads:*
The program is exiting upon entering the ANTLR Lexer constructor (as indicated below).
No catch clause or error logging is seen on the console. I am using NLog for logging (which according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54406989/13111872) comment is thread safe).

I am using ANTLR 4.11.1 (JAR, targeting C#) and have not modified the parser or lexer in any way from the generated code.

**Why is multithreading preventing me from stepping into the lexer constructor, and why is it also concealing the error logging?**

```cs
   // The entry point for this process
   public Task<Scope> StartLoadingScope (Uri uri)
        {
            // Safety checks to prevent double loading

            Task<Scope> task = new Task<Scope>(() =>
            {
                return LoadScopeSync(uri);
            });

            task.Start();
            return task;
        }
```

```cs
    // Called from StartLoadingScope
    private Scope LoadScopeSync (Uri uri)
        {
            string text = // Get the text

            Scope scope = ParseScopeText(uri, text);

            return scope;
        }
```

```cs
    // Called from LoadScopeSync
    private Scope ParseScopeText (Uri source, string textIn)
        {
            try
            {
                // Setup ANTLR
                AntlrInputStream a4is = new AntlrInputStream(textIn);
                
                // Multithreaded program fails/exits upon entering this constructor
                // If I try to step into it with the Visual Studio debugger, the program
                // exits immediately
                CrimsonLexer lexer = new CrimsonLexer(a4is);
                CommonTokenStream cts = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
                CrimsonParser parser = new CrimsonParser(cts);

                // Setup error handling
                string sourceName = $"{source}";
                lexer.AddErrorListener(new LexerErrorListener(sourceName));
                parser.ErrorHandler = new ParserErrorStrategy(sourceName);

                // Visit the scope
                CrimsonParser.ScopeContext cuCtx = parser.scope();
                ScopeVisitor visitor = new ScopeVisitor();
                Scope scope = visitor.VisitScope(cuCtx);

                return scope;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // This catch clause is never seen on the console
                LOGGER.Error("An error ocurred while parsing a scope");
                Console.WriteLine("An error ocurred while parsing a scope");
                throw new StatementParseException("A parser error occurred :(", ex);
            }
        }
```

```cs
    // Part of my ANTLR visitor (called indirectly via ParseScopeText)
    public override Scope VisitScope ([NotNull] CrimsonParser.ScopeContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                // Some things...

                // Visit imports
                IList<CrimsonParser.ImportUnitContext> importCtxs = context._imports;
                foreach (CrimsonParser.ImportUnitContext importCtx in importCtxs)
                {
                    // This line throws an exception
                    Uri uri = new Uri(importCtx.uri.Text);
                    FullNameCToken id = VisitFullName(importCtx.fullName());
                    ImportCStatement import = new ImportCStatement(uri, id);
                    scope.Imports.Add(id.ToString(), import);
                }

                // More things...
            }

            // This catch clause is also never seen on the console
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LOGGER.Error("VisitScope encountered an error!");
                Console.WriteLine("VisitScope encountered an error!");
                throw new StatementParseException("Unable to parse scope :(", ex);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for information on handling errors in C# Tasks, I found the following sites of interest:

1. [SO - How to handle Task.Run exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32067034/how-to-handle-task-run-exception)
2. [SO - How to throw an exception in a C# thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773959/throw-an-exception-in-thread-c-sharp)
3. [Microsoft - Handling exceptions in async methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch#exceptions-in-async-methods)

My understanding from this is that exceptions will only propagate upwards (i.e. be thrown in the parent thread) if the task is `await`ed or `Task.Wait()` is called.

Hence, by calling `Wait()` on a task and surrounding it with a try-catch, you can catch exceptions thrown within the Task. This has solved the issue.